# How to catch Timeout with mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I have a pythonscript with mechanize that read a list of urls from a text file. There are around 6000 urls. When it reaches around 3000, the script get hang. I noticed this when I saw the script was using 0% processing power.

So, I used python-dbg to check whats happening. I found that at some url, it get stuck. I tried adding a timeout to the url fetching line, but it did not work.

So is there any way , I can add a timeout and continue with next url, if it takes so much time to load?

```
from json import loads
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13")]

with open('mf.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            google_results = br.open("https://www.abcd.com" + str(line), timeout=0).read()
            json_obj = loads(google_results)
            if json_obj["ruleGroups"]["USABILITY"]["pass"] == True:
                print str(line), "Good"
            else:
                print str(line), "Bad"


        except Exception as e:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this `br.set_handle_refresh(False)` along with `timeout=0`